# How to get the r.js build script working

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I've read through the documentation and the example app.build.js file but just can't get my js files to concatenate and minify into one single file.  I think I'm just not understanding exactly what settings I need in the build script and was hoping for some help.

My app is set up like this:

```
src >
    js >
        build.js
        r.js
        config.js
        app >
            main.js
        lib >
            module1.js
            module2.js
            module3.js
        vendor >
            require.js
            jquery.js
            jquery.validation.js

build >
    // Where concat and minified file would go
```

**config.js** looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl" : "src/js/lib", // Used because when setting dependencies in modules, this is used
    "paths" : {
        "app" : "../app",
        "jquery" : [
            "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min",
            "../vendor/jquery"
        ],
        "validate" : "../vendor/jquery.validate.min"
    },
    "shim" : {
        // Allow plugins with dependencies to load asynchronously
        validate : ["jquery"]
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

**main.js** looks like this:

```
require(["module1", "module2", "module3"], function(Module1, Module2, Module3) {

    return [
        Module1.init(),
        Module2.init(),
        Module3.init(),
        Module4.init()
    ];

});
```

And then the **build.js** is where I'm lost.  I thought I should load a mainConfigFile because I'm using the shim, but I'm not sure.  If I do load that config file, it uses the baseUrl from that config file.  I'm not sure what `name:` is supposed to refer to exactly and whether I'm missing some necessary configuration options.

```
({
    //baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty:",
        //main: "../app/main",
        //app: "app"
    },
    name: "app/main",
    out: "../build/main.js",
    //mainConfigFile: "config"
})
```

If I run that build file as it is (with those lines commented out) I get:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/Users/davidpaul/Sites/require/src/js/module1.js' In module tree:
>       app/main

I'm not really sure what's being referred to when it says 'module tree'.  I keep making changes to paths in the build file but not making progress so hoping for someone to explain this a bit to me.

Comment: Where does the word "alpha" appear in your code? You should include this file in the question as well.

Comment: Sorry @kryger, that's a typo.  I renamed my filenames for this question to make it simpler but forgot to do so with the error.  Alpha was a module which I renamed to module1.  I've edited the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The builder parses all paths relative to the build file location (unless [changed via the baseUrl property](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/2.1.15/build/example.build.js#L21-L25)). If you look relative to `src/js/build.js`, your **main.js** is in `./app/` and **module1/2/3.js** are in `./lib/`. All paths inside modules have to be specified relatively to the common root, so to make your example work it's enough to change the signature of **main.js** to:

```
require(["lib/module1", "lib/module2", "lib/module3"], function(M1, M2, M3) {
   // (...)
})
```

---

Note that **config.js** doesn't take part in the build process, you may need to change it as well to make your application work both "raw" and optimized.